# how to compute TF-IDF on dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I have data set of articles and how much every word appear in those articles: 
how to calculate TF-IDF?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as sk
import math 

data = pd.read_csv('D:\\Datasets\\NIPS_1987-2015.csv', index_col ="word")

# retrieving row by loc method
first = data["1987_1"]
second = data["1987_2"]

print(first, "\n\n\n", second)
```

I get this DB:

```
word
abalone        0
abbeel         0
abbott         0
abbreviate     0
abbreviated    0
          ..
zoo            0
zoom           0
zou            0
zoubin         0
zurich         0
Name: 1987_1, Length: 11463, dtype: int64 


 word
abalone        0
abbeel         0
abbott         0
abbreviate     0
abbreviated    0
          ..
zoo            0
zoom           0
zou            0
zoubin         0
zurich         0
Name: 1987_2, Length: 11463, dtype: int64
```

so from here how to calculate TF-IDF? any suggestions? should I convert to a dictionary or there's another possibility?

Comment: Can you provide some data? What would you expect to come out? This looks to me like you're importing an array of words, and you're using the words as index... Is the output as you expect it, so far? Or is there something not according to your expectation?

Comment: it's the number of occurrences of each word. yeah, the words like indexes. there are lots of zeros in both articles. abalone for example not in these 2 articles but appears in another article. currently, I check only this both articles. but for example I have a word "written" who appears 1 in 1987_1 and 3 in 1987_2

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following. Let's assume you got the `docs` which is a list of `pd.Series` objects and each represent the word frequency distribution of a single doc.

Then you can reconstruct a corpus (the order of the words doesn't matter just the frequency matters for TF-IDF).

Finally you use `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer` to convert your corpus to TF-IDF values.

**Note**: This assumes that your text (once reconstructed) can be fit in memory. Most datasets are. But if it is not the case and if you want TF-IDF straight from `docs`, you probably will have to implement it yourself.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

# docs = [pd.Series(...), pd.Series(..), ...]

rep_docs = [" ".join(d.repeat(d).index.values) for d in docs]

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf.fit(rep_docs)
res = tfidf.transform(rep_docs[:1])

print(res)
print(tfidf.vocabulary_)
```

which produces,

```
# TF IDF values
(0, 10) 0.2773500981126146
(0, 8)  0.2773500981126146
(0, 5)  0.8320502943378437
(0, 4)  0.2773500981126146
(0, 1)  0.2773500981126146

# Vocabulary
{'sat': 8, 'the': 10, 'mat': 4, 'bark': 1, 'moon': 5, 'on': 7, 'at': 0, 'swam': 9, 'to': 11, 'ocean': 6, 'fish': 3, 'cat': 2}
```

Comment: Thank you it really helped! I try to do functions and it's very complicated and I almost got it but your option is the fastest. Thank You!

Comment: In regards to the vocabulary. for example, I have the word "work" which occurs in the 2 articles ( 1 in the first article and 3 in the second )so why I only see the value in the first article but not in the second? also, the first column means the number of document? (the column with the zeros)